# About Compile Function

Tags: functions

I have a function that take p as a parameter, p is a 2X3X3 list,

(
a 2X3X3 list can like { {{2,3},{1,2.},{1,1.}},  {{2,3.},{1,2},{1,1}},  {{2,3},{1,2},{1,1}} }
)

the function just as:

```
func[p_]:= Module[{}, {Main Fuction} ];
```

If I want to use Complie Function:

```
func= Compile[{p,_Real,???},
Module[{}, {Main Fuction} ]
];

How do I define ??? (above)
```

Comment: Try and read your own question to see if it is clear enough, because I have hard time understanding it.

Comment: `???` is `Length@Dimensions[p]`. In this case, 3.

Comment: @Oleksandr I would (and did) use `TensorRank` myself. :^)

Comment: Considering the code you showed in your previous question, I want to remind you that `Compile` isn't a panacea for speed, it'll lead to more limitation in programming and may bring you endless grief indeed. Have you already read [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1096/1871) and [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1803/1871) post?

Comment: @  xzczd, You are so clever, I just want to add a Compile Function to speed up my code, But found it cannot.....

Comment: Well, you should not place a space between "@" and my name, or I won't get the reminder.

Comment: BTW, If you feel satisfied with an answer, you can accept it by clicking the tick at the left-top corner of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Compile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Compile.html):

[image]

[`TensorRank`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TensorRank.html):

[image]

```
{ {{2,3},{1,2.},{1,1.}}, {{2,3.},{1,2},{1,1}}, {{2,3},{1,2},{1,1}} } // TensorRank
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

Therefore:

```
cfn = Compile[{{p, _Real, 3}}, Plus @@@ p];

{{{2, 3}, {1, 2.}, {1, 1.}}, {{2, 3.}, {1, 2}, {1, 1}}, {{2, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 1}}} // cfn
```

> ```
> {{4., 6.}, {4., 6.}, {4., 6.}}
> ```

If you are using an older version of *Mathematica* use [`ArrayDepth`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ArrayDepth.html) instead.

Comment: ♦, I have got it, Thanks