# Apply functions to functions yields slow execution speed

Tags: functions, performance-tuning, compile

I'm trying to write a function that parametrizes a curve c(t) by its arc length. Technicly I'm finished but if I plot the result for an example curve like `t * {Cos[t], Sin[t]}` it returns the result but it is really slow (2 min 37 sec).
I already tried out every optimazation I can imagine (pre-compile the functions using `Compile`, choosing `CompilationTarget -> "C"`) but the result is still to slow.
I think I might do something stupid by applying so many functions repeatively but I cannot figure out what.
Here is my program:

```
a = 0;
c = Compile[{t}, t * {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, CompilationTarget -> "C"];
phi = Compile[{t1}, Integrate[Norm[c'[t]], {t, a, t1}],CompilationTarget -> "C"];
psi = Compile[{d}, InverseFunction[phi][d], CompilationTarget -> "C"];
g = Compile[{s}, c[psi[s]], CompilationTarget -> "C"];
Plot[g[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Hi! Most likely the majority of your functions do not benefit from compilation, see e.g. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1803/131. `Plot` may sample many points. If that is your bottleneck, then a `Table` with a defined number of points together with `ListPlot` might be an option.

Comment: @YvesKlett Indeed, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions shows that `Integrate` and `InverseFunction` are not compilable, or at least not in that list.

Comment: @blochwave ah, that was the one I was actually looking for :D

Comment: So if `Integrate` and `InverseFunction` are not compilable I should remove the `Compile` commands? But that slows down again the computation time.. Even without the `Plot` method querying just one specific value takes to much time. Is there nothing I can do speed it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want, but this is much faster:

```
ClearAll[a, c, phi, t1, psi, g];
a = 0;
c[t_] := t*{Cos[t], Sin[t]}
phi = Integrate[Sqrt[c'[t].c'[t]], {t, a, t1}, Assumptions -> t1 \[Element] Reals && t1 > 0];
psi = InverseFunction[Function[{t1}, Evaluate@phi]];
g[s_] := g[s] = c[psi[s]]
ParametricPlot[g[x], {x, 0, 40}, PlotRange -> All, 
               Epilog -> Point@Table[g[i], {i, 40}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Wow,that's exactly what I was looking for! How did you rpoduce that speedup? Are `phi` and `psi` now some kind of macros instead of functions?