# How to do this Function with compile

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, compile

There is 4 lists, 3 of them are at same length (`l0`, `l1` and `l3`).

```
l0={2,3,4,2,5};
l1={{1,2},{2,4},{3,1},{4,3},{5,1}};
l2={{1,2},{1,3},{2,1},{3,1},{4,5},{5,4}};
l3={0,0,0,0,0};
```

Each member of `l0` should be comparison with second element of corresponding member of `l1`, if it was greater we call them Beep members.(here third and fifth member of `l0`), then from `l2` we choose members that have equal value at first element with Beep (first element) and call them Ops. At last add one to each element of `l3` at position Ops[[2]] .

here: Beep: `{3,1}` and `{5,1}`, Ops: `{3,1}` and `{5,4}` and finally `l3={1,0,0,1,0}`.

I write a function that do this, Is it best way for doing this?

```
Func[l0_] := 
  Module[{l3 = ConstantArray[0, n]}, 
   MapThread[
     If[#1 > #2[[2]], ++l3[[
         Cases[l2, {x_, y_} /; x == #2[[1]] :> y]]]] &, {l0, l1}];
   ];
```

How to Compile it?

Comment: `l3[[#]] ++ & /@ 
 Last /@ Cases[
   l2, {Alternatives @@ (First /@ 
       Pick[l1, Thread[l0 > Last /@ l1]]), _}]`

Comment: Is the length of sublists of `l1` and `l2` always `2`?

Comment: Thanks, @Dr.belisarius, But how can do it in compile?

Comment: @xzczd yes, always. And first element of each member of `l1` is their position.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `Func` is far beyond best. As mentioned before, currently you'd better set effort on learning to code in "*Mathematica*-style" rather than try to relieve the slowness (which is mostly caused by bad coding in my view) with `Compile`. Here's an uncompiled function that's about 300 times faster than your `Func`:

```
func = Function[{l0, l1, l2, ll3}, Module[{l3 = ll3, beep, oops},
    beep = First@Transpose@Pick[l1, UnitStep[Last@Transpose@l1 - l0], 0]; 
    oops = Pick[Last@Transpose@l2, First@Transpose@l2, #] & /@ beep // Flatten; 
    l3[[#]]++&/@oops; l3]];

n = 10^4;
l0 = RandomInteger[{1, n}, n];
l1 = Transpose[{Range@n, RandomInteger[{1, n}, n]}];
l2 = RandomInteger[{1, n}, {n, 2}];
l3 = ConstantArray[0, Length@l0];

rst1 = func[l0, l1, l2, l3]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.385027, Null} *)

Func[l0]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {125.067177, Null} *)
```

If you still insist on learning the usage of `Compile`, I suggest you to start from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104031/1871), and if speed is really really concerned, here's the fastest approach I found so far:

```
cf2 = ReleaseHold@
  With[{g = Compile`GetElement}, 
   Hold@Compile[{{l0, _Integer, 1}, {l1, _Integer, 2}, {l2, _Integer, 2}, {ll3, _Integer,
          1}}, Module[{l3 = ll3, n = Length@l0, m = Length@l2, index}, 
        Do[If[l0[[i]] > l1[[i, 2]], 
          Do[If[l2[[j, 1]] == l1[[i, 1]], ++l3[[l2[[j, 2]]]]], {j, m}]], {i, n}]; l3], 
       CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] //. 
     HoldPattern[Part[b__]] :> g[b] //. HoldPattern[++g[b__]] :> ++Part[b]]

rst2 = cf2[l0, l1, l2, l3]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.053404, Null} *)
rst1 == rst2
(* True *)
```

Notice a C compiler should be installed on your computer.

Comment: Yep. A better advice than mine anyway