# Compile error with MapThread

Tags: list-manipulation, compile

I have the following code:

```
s[x_Real, y_Real, z_Real, w_Real] = {{x + I y, - z + I w}, { z + I w, x - I y}};
ssamp = Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {nd, _Integer}}, MapThread[s, Transpose[Map[
  Normalize, RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {n, nd, 4}],{2}], {3, 2, 1}] , 2]]
```

The `compile` fails with error messages

- MapThread::list: List expected at position 2
- Compile::cprank: Compile cannot determine the rank of the result tensor.

If I remove the MapThread, the function compiles. Any suggestions for getting it to compile?

Comment: Check [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1096/193). I can't find `Normalize` and `NormalDistribution`

Comment: Personally I also suggest you to read this answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104031/1871

Comment: @Dr.belisarius The `Normalize` and `NormalDistribution` are not the problem since it compiles if I remove `MapThread`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a fully compiled version, principles applied in modifying the code has been mentioned in the links above:

```
ssamp2 = Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {nd, _Integer}}, 
  Partition[Function[xyzw, {{xyzw[[1]] + I xyzw[[2]], 
                             -xyzw[[3]] + I xyzw[[4]]}, 
                            {xyzw[[3]] + I xyzw[[4]], 
                             xyzw[[1]] - I xyzw[[2]]}}]@#/Sqrt@Total[#^2] & /@ 
   RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {n nd, 4}], n]]
```

Comment: Now that you've written it so nicely, it is clear that we can throw away the `Flatten` and `Transpose` and just replace the `{n,nd,4}` with `{n*nd,4}`.

Comment: The key thing that makes this work seems to be to normalize the vectors first, then pass them to the function defined within the `Function[ , ]`. May I ask how you figured this out?

Comment: @syhpphys I think the 2 key points here are 1. `Normalize` can not be compiled so one needs to replace it with a compiled equivalent i.e. `#/Sqrt@Total[#^2] &` . 2. function defined with **pattern-matching** cannot be compiled (see the 3rd rule [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104031/1871)?), so one needs to replace it with a pure function, which can _usually_ be compiled if it's formed by compilable function.

Comment: @syhpphys "we can throw away the `Flatten` and `Transpose` and just replace the `{n,nd,4}` with `{n*nd,4}`" You are right, I forgot to take the code inside `RandomVariate` into account, thanks for pointing out, edited.

Comment: @xzczd +1 to your answer. In comments you wrote: "function defined with pattern-matching cannot be compiled". Very good comment, not only this phrase. Also +1. But in the next Mathematica it will be possible: https://youtu.be/P2tr7A1LOLA?list=PLxn-kpJHbPx0po0k_FiuFqDuVotoZhX7_&t=950 A lot of cool things expected ^_^

Comment: @AlexeyGolyshev Wow, seems that I'll have a lot of answers to revise soon :D

Answer (score 3):

You can replace `MapThread[func,list,2]` with `func/@Transpose[Flatten/@list]`.

```
s[{x_Real,y_Real,z_Real,w_Real}]:={{x+I y,-z+I w},{z+I w,x-I y}};

ssamp = Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {nd, _Integer}},
  s /@
   Transpose[
    Flatten /@ 
     Transpose[
      Map[Normalize, 
       RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {n, nd, 4}], {2}], {3, 2, 1}]
    ]
  ]
```

When you evaluate this compiled function, first 3 times and only 3 times (it's very strange!) you will see such error message.

```
ssamp[2, 2]
```

> CompiledFunction::cfex: Could not complete external evaluation at instruction 36; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>

But `CompilePrint` looks okay.

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
CompilePrint@ssamp

"
        2 arguments
        17 Integer registers
        2 Real registers
        7 Tensor registers
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking on
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        I0 = A1
        I1 = A2
        I3 = 0
        I2 = 4
        T(I1)6 = {3, 2, 1}
        I14 = -1
        I4 = 1
        I16 = 3
        Result = T(R2)0

1   T(I1)1 = {I0, I1, I2}
2   R0 = I3
3   R1 = I4
4   T(R3)3 = RandomNormal[ R0, R1, T(I1)1]]
5   I8 = Length[ T(R3)3]
6   T(R2)0 = Part[ T(R3)3, I4]
7   I11 = Length[ T(R2)0]
8   I15 = I14
9   T(R3)0 = Table[ I8, I11, I15]
10  I12 = I3
11  goto 18
12  I13 = I3
13  goto 17
14  T(R1)4 = GetElement[ T(R3)3, I12, I13]
15  T(R1)5 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[Normalize][ T(R1)4]]
16  Element[ T(R2)0, I15] = T(R1)5
17  if[ ++ I13 <= I11] goto 14
18  if[ ++ I12 <= I8] goto 12
19  T(R3)3 = Transpose[ T(R3)0, T(I1)6, I16]]
20  I6 = Length[ T(R3)3]
21  I9 = I14
22  T(R2)0 = Table[ I6, I9]
23  I7 = I3
24  goto 28
25  T(R2)5 = GetElement[ T(R3)3, I7]
26  T(R1)4 = Flatten[ T(R2)5, I4]]
27  Element[ T(R2)0, I9] = T(R1)4
28  if[ ++ I7 <= I6] goto 25
29  T(R2)3 = Transpose[ T(R2)0]]
30  I5 = Length[ T(R2)3]
31  I6 = I14
32  T(R2)0 = Table[ I5, I6]
33  I9 = I3
34  goto 38
35  T(R1)4 = GetElement[ T(R2)3, I9]
36  T(R1)5 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[s][ T(R1)4]]
37  Element[ T(R2)0, I6] = T(R1)5
38  if[ ++ I9 <= I5] goto 35
39  Return
"
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Well, I don't think  the `15  T(R1)5 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[Normalize][ T(R1)4]]` and `36  T(R1)5 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[s][ T(R1)4]]
` lines look OK…

Comment: "When you evaluate this compiled function, first 3 times and only 3 times (it's very strange!) you will see such error message" it's because the warning is suppressed then. (I understand it as a silent `General::stop`. ) To see a similar behavior, execute `f = f[x]` for 3 times.

Comment: @xzczd Executed `f = f[x]` 20 times - no suppression. `$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of f[x].`

Comment: What's your version? I observed this behavior in v8.0.4 and v9.0.1. Here's the screenshot for v8.0.4: http://i.stack.imgur.com/tOlHH.png

Comment: @xzczd v10.3.1 http://www.fastswf.com/jgyvaTM

Comment: Oh, so v10.3.1 has handled this problem in a better way :)

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work  (at least on v9):

```
s[{x_Real, y_Real, z_Real, w_Real}] := {{x + I y, -z + I w}, {z + I w, x - I y}}


ssamp = Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {nd, _Integer}},
  Module[{u1},
   u1 = Transpose[
         Map[Normalize, RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {n, nd, 4}], {2}], 
         {3, 2, 1}];
   s /@ Transpose[Flatten /@ u1]], 
   {{s[__], _Complex, 2}},
  CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}];

ssamp[2, 2] // Grid
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It works, but it is slower compared to the original version when not compiled; speed is the only reason I am compiling.