# Evaluating ReplaceAll inside SetDelayed, first

Tags: performance-tuning, function-construction, evaluation, replacement, assignment

Consider the following (simplified for the purpose of example) definitions:

```
f[x_] := y /. y -> x
g[x_] := x
```

Where for example, the definition of `f` could be motivated e.g. by first getting some expression (`y`) from a previous calculation, and then deciding to make it into a function.

The problems begin when f is then passed on to a third function, that evaluates it many times (e.g. `NIntegrate`, `Plot`, etc), or maybe I then attempt to `Compile` it. Due to the replacement rule that is saved as part of the definition, everything will be much slower, as can be seen in the following trace:

```
In[23]:= Trace[f[1]]
Out[23]= {f[1],y/. y->1,{y->1,y->1},y/. y->1,1}
```

vs

```
Trace[g[1]]
{g[1],1}
```

I suspect though I am not certain and haven't profiled this, that the first operation would be significantly slower even when compared to evaluating a more complex mathematical expression, provided it consists of built in functions. I'm open to this being refuted, but my interest is only partly driven by efficiency, so I won't accept an answer that simply refutes my assumption without answering the actual question (I would still find it useful, however).

Now, a plausible way to avoid the previous conundrum is to wrap the RHS of `SetDelayed` by `Evaluate` This has its own problems however, namely evaluating unintended parts:

```
In[16]:= z=1
Out[16]= 1
...
In[42]:= k[x_]:=Evaluate[z+y/.y->x]
In[35]:= Trace[k[1]]
Out[35]= {k[1],1}
In[44]:= Definition[k]
Out[44]= k[x_]:=1+x
```

What are other methods making the ReplaceAll evaluate once, and what (possibly unintended) consequences do they have? I am mainly interested in something lightweight, that I might actually use in notebooks without my init.m file - not in defining a largs expression to manipulate the SetDelayed lines (though that would still be interesting from an intellectual point of view).

Ideally, this would work (it doesn't)
    (f[x_]:=y)/.y->x

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe your question is oversimplified... I just want to point out 1. `k[x_]:=Evaluate[z+y/.y->x]` has the same effect as `k2[x_]=z+y/.y->x` and `k3[x_]:=z+x`. (Check `DownValues/@{k,k2,k3}`) 2. Function definition based on pattern matching can't be compiled directly, for more information you may want to read [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104031/1871).

Comment: @xzczd You are right about the equivalence of the first two, wrong about the equivalence to the third (would be right if it was `Set` and not `SetDelayed` there): `{HoldPattern[k[x_]] :> 1 + x, HoldPattern[k2[x_]] :> 1 + x, HoldPattern[k3[x_]] :> z + x}` and that was precisely the point - I want to get from `k[x_]:=y+z` to `k[x_]:=x+z` rather than to `k[x_] = x+z`

Comment: Oh, so you want `y` be replaced while `z` be unevaluated. I think this should stated in a clearer way in the body of the question. As to this specific example, a solution I can think out is: `Unevaluated@(k[x_] := y + z) /. y -> x`

Comment: If I understand you correctly, is `f[x_] := z + y /. y -> x` too slow when used like this (`z` becomes a number eventually?): `Plot[f[x], {x,-1,1}]`?  Even if that's true... I don't think I quite understand you because of the `z`.  Can you provide a next-to-minimal example?

Comment: @xzczd It appears that this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I will try to edit the question, and you are of course also welcome to suggest an edit. 

If you add the comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @QuantumDot the main issue is not the speed but the process of evaluation. I don't have a less trivial example right now, but will add one when it eventually comes up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, let me extend my comment to an answer. As mentioned in your question:

> Ideally, this would work (it doesn't) `(f[x_]:=y)/.y->x`

That attempt doesn't succeed because `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) is a function that doesn't have `HoldAll` etc. attribute and it evaluates its argument before the replacement. To resolve the problem we need to stop the auto evaluation in some way, for example:

```
z = 1;

(* Solution 1 *)
Unevaluated@(k[x_] := y + z) /. y -> x

(* Solution 2 *)
Hold[k2[x_] := y + z] /. y -> x // ReleaseHold

DownValues /@ {k, k2}
(* {{HoldPattern[k[x_]] :> x + z}, {HoldPattern[k2[x_]] :> x + z}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks! came to think that it was all about the Precedence of the operators and forgot about the hold... I'm surprised there isn't a version of ReplaceAll with both a higher precedence and a hold - I guess I'll need to write one for myself.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is to use [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set) instead of [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed), and use [`Unevaluated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated) to prevent evaluation:

```
z = 1;
f[x_] = With[{y = x}, Unevaluated @ Unevaluated[y + z]];
DownValues[f]
```

> {HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> x + z}