# ReplaceAll does not work

Tags: evaluation, replacement

Why ReplaceAll does not work in this situation?

```
id = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
sx = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}};
sy = {{0, -I}, {I, 0}};
sz = {{1, 0}, {0, -1}};
s = {id, sx, sy, sz};
p[t_] := {p0[t], p1[t], p2[t], 
  p3[t]}; 

In[1]:= 
Sum[p[1][[i]]*s[[i]].sx.s[[i]], {i, 1, 4}] /. p[1] -> {1, 0, 0, 0}

Out[1]= {{0, 
  p0[1] + p1[1] - p2[1] - p3[1]}, {p0[1] + p1[1] - p2[1] - p3[1], 0}}
```

The output is right, only the replacement of the terms in vector p[t] does not take place.

Comment: Strongly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128438/1871 There should be more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because

```
p[1] -> {1, 0, 0, 0}
```

evaluates to

```
{p0[1], p1[1], p2[1], p3[1]} -> {1, 0, 0, 0}
```

and the left side of this rule does not appear in your expression. What you want is,

```
MapThread[Rule, {p[1], {1, 0, 0, 0}}]
```

which evaluates to the *list* of rules

```
{p0[1] -> 1, p1[1] -> 0, p2[1] -> 0, p3[1] -> 0}
```

Using `ReplaceAll` with that list of rules gives the result,

```
{{0, 1}, {1, 0}}
```