# Can I compile my function?

Tags: performance-tuning, compile

I'm trying to do some time-consuming simulations but I have no idea how to optimize this.

```
sim[dist_, expectDist_, n_] := 
  Block[{sample, test, freq}, 
    sample = Table[RandomVariate[dist, #], n] & /@ {5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200}; 
    test = 
       Map[TTest[#, expectDist, VerifyTestAssumptions -> None] &, sample, {2}]; 
    freq = Count[#, p_ /; p <= 0.05] & /@ test; 
    N[freq 100/n]]

sim[NormalDistribution[], 0, 10000]
```

Comment: Unfortunately if you look at ``Compile`CompilerFunctions[] // Sort`` `TTest` isn't there so you won't be able to compile that.

Comment: Also, only uniform and normal distribution can be compiled with random variate. Besides, the argument of a compiled function can only be integer, real, complex, boolean, and tensors of them, nothing like `dist` would be allowed. Your code is impossible to compile, unless you implement the algorithms yourself.

Comment: Also, your code inside `Compile` involves pattern pattern matching, which cannot be compiled, see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104031/1871) for more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In response to...

> I have no idea how to optimize this

Here's my shot at it. `TTest` seems slow, perhaps because `InverseCDF`/`CDF` on the `StudentTDistribution` is called for each test.  Below, I do it just once for each sample size to get the critical value and omit the P-value, a big savings of time.  One can then just perform the T-test by hand.  There is no need or advantage to compile it.  It's almost 250 times as fast as the OP's approach.

```
sim[dist_, expectDist_, n_] := 
 Module[{sample, test, freq, cv, samplesizes},
  samplesizes = {5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200};    (* not sure if this should be a parameter *)
  sample = RandomVariate[dist, {n, #}] & /@ samplesizes; (* gets n samples of each size *)
  cv = InverseCDF[StudentTDistribution[# - 1], 0.975] & /@ samplesizes;  (* crit. vals. *)
  test = MapThread[                                    (* calculate Abs[test stat] - CV *)
    Sqrt@#3 Abs[Mean /@ # - expectDist] / StandardDeviation /@ # - #2 &,
    {sample, cv, samplesizes}];
  freq = Total[UnitStep[test], {2}];   (* counts nonnegative differences: total rejects *)
  N[freq 100/n]]
```

Comment: Thanks, now I can make n = 100000 pretty fast.

Answer (score 3):

Answer from comments:

> Unfortunately if you look at `` Compile`CompilerFunctions[] // Sort `` `TTest` isn't there so you won't be able to compile that. – MB1965
>
> ... Only uniform and normal distribution can be compiled with random variate. Besides, the argument of a compiled function can only be integer, real, complex, boolean, and tensors of them, nothing like `dist` would be allowed. Your code is impossible to compile, unless you implement the algorithms yourself. – happy fish
>
> ... Your code inside `Compile` involves pattern pattern matching, which cannot be compiled, see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104031/1871) for more information. – xzczd