# Faster sum of products of tuples?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, summation

My function:

```
  sumprob[lst_,size_]:=Sum[Product[x,{x,part}],{part,Tuples[lst,{size}]}];
```

Example:

```
   sumprob[Range[1, 50, 3], 5]
```

> 13865791015625

How might I speed this up?

Comment: `Total[Times @@@ Tuples[lst, {size}]]`?

Answer (score 4):

For optimization, worth playing around with and comparing a few different almost identical ways of doing the same thing.  What seems like *just* syntactic sugar can sometimes cost:

```
In[1]:= sumprobAtCubed[lst__, size_] := Total[Times @@@ Tuples[lst, {size}]]

In[2]:= sumprobAtMap[lst__, size_] := Total[(Times @@ #) & /@ Tuples[lst, {size}]]

In[3]:= AbsoluteTiming[sumprobAtMap[xxx = RandomInteger[{1, 50}, 20], 5]]

Out[3]= {0.743279, 77114156402999}

In[4]:= AbsoluteTiming[sumprobAtCubed[xxx, 5]]

Out[4]= {4.352, 77114156402999}

In[5]:= xxx

Out[5]= {45, 48, 49, 17, 25, 8, 50, 31, 32, 27, 33, 36, 43, 16, 30, 35, 33, 29, 9, 3}

In[6]:= RepeatedTiming[sumprobAtMap[xxx, 5]]    

Out[6]= {0.618, 77114156402999}

In[7]:= RepeatedTiming[sumprobAtCubed[xxx, 5]]

Out[7]= {4.3, 77114156402999}

In[8]:= sumprob[lst_, size_] := Sum[Product[x, {x, part}], {part, Tuples[lst, {size}]}];

In[9]:= AbsoluteTiming[sumprob[xxx, 5]] (* Compare with poster's orig *)

Out[9]= {12.4336, 77114156402999}
```

(V.11.1 Mac OS)

Edit:  Thanks ciao -- *solving* the problem should always win ;-)

```
In[14]:= AbsoluteTiming[Tr[xxx]^5]

Out[14]= {0.000017, 77114156402999}
```

Comment: I'd venture the version with map is getting auto-compiled. In any case, away from machines so can't test but seems like `sumthing[l_,s_]:=Tr[l]^s;` should do the trick quickly...

Comment: @ciao I think you're right re: auto-comp.  Worth including a link to this  question on [compilation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-compile-effectively) where Leonid Shifrin's answer has a nice discussion of Map and auto-compile.

Answer (score 3):

Although not as fast as ciao's formula the direct computation can be done more quickly like this, assuming the input list is all positive numbers:

```
sumprob2[lst_, size_] := Tr @ Exp @ Total[Tuples[N @ Log @ lst, {size}], {2}];

sumprob2[Range[1, 50, 3], 5] // Round // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0511, 13865791015625}
> ```

Reference:

- [Is there a fast product operation for PackedArrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5294640/618728) (Stack Overflow)

Comment: I like this, and nice reference.  Perhaps worth warning about introduction of finite-precision arithmetic for speedup due to the `N[#]&`. I.e. Combined with the exp and log games, something like `sumprob2[{10^4},5]` will have an error of $O(10^5)$, so best with small integers etc.   Still great trick, thanks for sharing! (+1)

Comment: @John Good point, I should have warned of that.  Old habits from Project Euler coming through, where I would use machine precision by default and check my answer, and only if it were wrong examine round-off errors.  Of course that's not a good way to proceed *in general*.