# Can any one help me make my program work faster?

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning

In order to construct the matrix `h1+h2`, I have used three `Table` commands. I am using `fxn[n1a_, n1b_, n2a_, n2b_]` as a function in a loop. I need my program to be a lot faster than what it is now, since this is only a part of my main program. Could any one tell me how I can make it work faster? In other words, what are the points I should pay attention to in Mathematica, in case of timing?

Description:

In the original program I am using an iteration method in which I need to construct the matrix `h1+h2`, calculate the new eigenvectors in each step, reconstruct the matrix `h1+h2`, until I observe convergence in eigenenergies.

`avec`, is a guessed vector, and I am using it as an initial vector to construct the matrix `h1+h2`.

Later on, I need to calculate the eigenvectors of this matrix, choose the vectors related to the minimum eigenvalues and put them instead of the previous `avec`.

`h1` is the kinetic term of my matrix and `h2` is the exchange potential (the formula which I have used came from the math I did for Hartree-Fock approximation).

`fxn` is a function I constructed based on the pre-calculated integrals in my code (so that I do not need to calculate the integrals in each iteration).

The problem now is the calculation for `h2`, which consumes most of the time. I assume the problem is the way I am using the `Table` commands. But I couldn't think of a more efficient way.

```
  avec = {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
  nvec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
  svec = {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
  kdfxn[i_, j_] := If[i == j, 1, 0]

  ne = 3;
  n\[Mu] = 12;
  \[Delta] = -50;
  \[Beta] = 1;

   fxn[n1a_, n1b_, n2a_, n2b_] := N[ Which[
   n1a == n1b && n2a == n2b,
   1/6 (1 - 3/(n1a^2 \[Pi]^2) - 3/(n2a^2 \[Pi]^2)),
   n1a == n1b && n2a != n2b,
   (4 (1 + (-1)^(n2a + n2b)) n2a n2b)/((n2a^2 - n2b^2)^2 \[Pi]^2),
   n1a != n1b && n2a == n2b,
   (4 (1 + (-1)^(n1a + n1b)) n1a n1b)/((n1a^2 - n1b^2)^2 \[Pi]^2),
   True, -((
    32 (-1 + (-1)^(n1a + n1b)) (-1 + (-1)^(
   n2a + n2b)) n1a n1b n2a n2b)/((n1a^2 - n1b^2)^2 (n2a^2 - 
   n2b^2)^2 \[Pi]^4))]]

hmat = Table[
n0 = nvec[[n\[Mu]0]];
n1 = nvec[[n\[Mu]1]];
h1 = (n0^2 \[Pi]^2 + \[Beta] svec[[n\[Mu]0]]) kdfxn[n\[Mu]0, 
  n\[Mu]1] ;
h2 = Total[Table[
  n2 = nvec[[n\[Mu]2]];
  n3 = nvec[[n\[Mu]3]];
  Table[
   temp1 = 
    fxn[n1, n0, n3, n2] avec[[j, n\[Mu]3]] avec[[j, n\[Mu]2]] ;
   temp2 = 
    fxn[n1, n3, n0, n2] avec[[j, n\[Mu]3]] avec[[j, n\[Mu]2]];
   temp = \[Delta] (temp1 - temp2), {j, 1, ne}],
  {n\[Mu]2, 1, n\[Mu]},
  {n\[Mu]3, 1, n\[Mu]}], Infinity];
  h1 + h2
 , {n\[Mu]0, 1, n\[Mu]}, {n\[Mu]1, 1, n\[Mu]}] // Timing
```

---

I want to use the code @Henrik Schumacher gave me to find my new avecs (which are coming from the eigenvectors of hcmat) to recalculate hcmat and iterate. The problem is I can do it manually by substituting new avec instead of the previous one, but as I start using table it doesn't work. I don't know why it's acting like that.

```
Table[chmat = 
    With[{ccfxn = cfxn}, 
    Compile[{{nm, _Integer}, {ne, _Integer}, {d, _Real}, {b, \
   _Real}, {avec, _Real, 2}, {nvec, _Real, 1}, {svec, _Real, 1}}, 
        Block[{n0, n1, n2, n3, h1, h2, tmp, tmp2}, 
        Table[n0 = Compile`GetElement[nvec, nm0];
        n1 = Compile`GetElement[nvec, nm1];
        tmp = 0.;
        Do[n2 = Compile`GetElement[nvec, nm2];
        n3 = Compile`GetElement[nvec, nm3];
        tmp2 = (ccfxn[n1, n0, n3, n2] - ccfxn[n1, n3, n0, n2]);

        Do[tmp += 
        tmp2 Compile`GetElement[avec, j, nm3] Compile`GetElement[
           avec, j, nm2], {j, 1, ne}], {nm2, 1, nm}, {nm3, 1, 
        nm}];
        d tmp + 
        If[nm0 == 
          nm1, (n0^2 Pi^2 + b Compile`GetElement[svec, nm0]), 
          0.], {nm0, 1, nm}, {nm1, 1, nm}]], 
       CompilationTarget -> "C", 
       CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}, 
       RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]];

       hmat2 = chmat[n\[Mu], ne, \[Delta], \[Beta], avec, nvec, svec]; //
       AbsoluteTiming // First
            hmat = hmat2

       eout = Eigensystem[hmat];
       evals = eout[[1]];
       evecs = eout[[2]];
       sortedevals = Sort[evals];
       bvec = Chop[Table[bpos = Position[evals, sortedevals[[i]]][[1, 1]];
       evecs[[bpos]], {i, 1, ne}]];
       Table[If[Sign[bvec[[i, 1]]] == Sign[avec[[i, 1]]], avec = ( bvec) , 
       avec = (Sign[avec[[i, 1]]] bvec) ], {i, 1, ne}];
       normalizedavec = Table[avec[[i]]/norm[avec, i], {i, 1, ne}];
       avec = normalizedavec;
       en = Total[Take[sortedevals, ne]], {j, 1, 5}]
```

### In the rest of the code, I am finding the first ne(3) minimum eigenenergies and finding the the related eigenvectors, to construct bvec. by doing some modification on bvec and normalizing it ,I could get the new avec I want to use instead of the previous one. Now my problem is doing the iteration. I would appreciate it if you could help me with this.

I want to calculate this integrals

```
 sol = Assuming[
 A \[Element] Reals && 0 <= s1 <= 1 && 1 <= n1a <= 10 && 
 1 <= n2a <= 10 && 1 <= n1b <= 10 && 1 <= n2b <= 10, 
 Expand@FullSimplify[
 Integrate[
  4 A Exp[-B (s2 - s1)] Sin[n1a \[Pi] s1] Sin[n1b \[Pi] s1] Sin[
    n2a \[Pi] s2] Sin[n2b \[Pi] s2], {s2, s1, 1}]]];

 sol1 = Assuming[
  A \[Element] Reals && 0 <= s2 <= 1 && 1 <= n1a <= 10 && 
  1 <= n2a <= 10 && 1 <= n1b <= 10 && 1 <= n2b <= 10, 
  Expand@FullSimplify[
  Integrate[
   4 A Exp[-B (s1 - s2)] Sin[n1a \[Pi] s1] Sin[n1b \[Pi] s1] Sin[
    n2a \[Pi] s2] Sin[n2b \[Pi] s2], {s1, s2, 1}]]];

(int[n1a_, n2a_, n1b_, n2b_] = 
 Integrate[sol, {s1, 0, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> 
  B \[Element] Reals && A \[Element] Reals && 1 <= n1a <= 10 && 
  1 <= n2a <= 10 && 1 <= n1b <= 10 && 1 <= n2b <= 10] + 
  Integrate[sol1, {s2, 0, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> 
  B \[Element] Reals && A \[Element] Reals && 1 <= n1a <= 10 && 
  1 <= n2a <= 10 && 1 <= n1b <= 10 && 1 <= n2b <= 10])
```

and replace n1a in the int function with n1a+0.0001 . Then I need to use the result of int after the replacement, as the material for code :code=result in:

```
        "cfxn = Block[{n1a, n1b, n2a, n2b}, 
         With[{code = "result"}, 
         Compile[{{n1a, _Integer}, {n1b, _Integer}, {n2a, _Integer}, {n2b, \
          _Integer}}, code, CompilationTarget -> "C"]]];"
```

but I am getting these errors:

> CompiledFunction::cfse: Compiled expression
>   CompiledFunction[{10,11.,5464},<<7>>,LibraryFunction[/Users/delaramnematollahi/Library/Mathematica/ApplicationData/CCompilerDriver/BuildFolder/Delarams-MacBook-Pro-3755/compiledFunction3.dylib,compiledFunction3,{<<1>>},{Real,2}]] should be a machine-size real number.

which I do not understand why.

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: It would be immensely more helpful if you could, besides the code, give explanation of what you want to achieve; e.g. what are matrices h1 and h2, how they are obtained, what is `fxn` supposed to do?

Comment: My avec, is a guessed vector, and I am using it as an initial vector to construct the matrix h1+h2, later on I need to calculate the Eigen vectors of this matrix and put instead of the previous avec.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the code.

Comment: @ercegovac  Sorry for that, I fixed that. I have also put an easier function from my previous program. but my actual function (fxn) is more complicated which I don't think I can do anything about that. I also edited my question and added some explanation. I hope that helps. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Again, the code is not reproducible. It appears that you did not  include at least `avec` and `nvec`. Verify that you have included all data by executing the code in the clean context by executing command `ClearAll["Global\`*"]`

Comment: @ercegovac  I tried it in new notebook, thank you

Comment: A few ideas:  fxn  must calculate either  4/pi^2  or  32/pi^4  every time.    Can that be factored out?   What's the fastest way to raise -1 to an integer power?  avec is full of zeros.  Does the code call  fxn  and then multiply the result by zero?  Instead of a function, maybe  fxn  should be a sparse array with a [`Band`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Band.html) structure.  Maybe  fxn  should be the sum of a [`Symmetric`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Symmetric.html) array and an [`Antisymmetric`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Antisymmetric.html) array.

Comment: Your update seems to be a new question.  If so, you should ask it separately.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Compile` can be your friend. Fortunately, your code is almost perfectly prodedural and thus can be compiled with only few changes.

```
avec = {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
nvec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
svec = {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
ne = 3;
nμ = 12;
δ = -50;
β = 1;

cfxn = Block[{n1a, n1b, n2a, n2b},
   With[{code = Which[
       n1a == n1b && n2a == n2b,
       Evaluate[N[1/6 (1 - 3/(n1a^2 π^2) - 3/(n2a^2 π^2))]],

       n1a == n1b && n2a != n2b,
       Evaluate[N[(4 (1 + (-1)^(n2a + n2b)) n2a n2b)/((n2a^2 - n2b^2)^2 π^2)]],

       n1a != n1b && n2a == n2b,
       Evaluate[N[(4 (1 + (-1)^(n1a + n1b)) n1a n1b)/((n1a^2 - n1b^2)^2 π^2)]],       

       True, 
       Evaluate[N[-((32 (-1 + (-1)^(n1a + n1b)) (-1 + (-1)^(n2a + n2b)) n1a n1b n2a n2b)/((n1a^2 - n1b^2)^2 (n2a^2 - n2b^2)^2 π^4))]]
       ]},
    Compile[{{n1a, _Integer}, {n1b, _Integer}, {n2a, _Integer}, {n2b, _Integer}},
     code,
     CompilationTarget -> "C"
     ]
    ]];
```

Here I tried to enforce that `cfxn` uses floating point numbers internally (therefore the `Evaluate`) such that less `Integer`s have to be type cast to `Real`s.

```
chmat = With[{ccfxn = cfxn},
   Compile[{{nm, _Integer}, {ne, _Integer}, {d, _Real}, {b, _Real}, {avec, _Real, 2}, {nvec, _Real, 1}, {svec, _Real, 1}},
    Block[{n0, n1, n2, n3, h1, h2, tmp, tmp2},
     Table[
      n0 = nvec[[nm0]];
      n1 = nvec[[nm1]];
      tmp = 0.;
      Do[
       n2 = nvec[[nm2]];
       n3 = nvec[[nm3]];
       tmp2 = (ccfxn[n1, n0, n3, n2] - ccfxn[n1, n3, n0, n2]);
       Do[tmp += tmp2 avec[[j, nm3]] avec[[j, nm2]], {j, 1, ne}],
        {nm2, 1, nm}, {nm3, 1, nm}];
      d tmp + If[nm0 == nm1, N[(n0^2 Pi^2 + b svec[[nm0]])], 0.],
      {nm0, 1, nm}, {nm1, 1, nm}]
     ],
    CompilationTarget -> "C",
    CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}
    ]];
```

**Edit:** My former implementation of `chmat` did not produce the correct result. I removed it and also optimized away the `Total`: Summing up the results in a fixed `Real` register has the advantage that no auxiliary arrays have to be allocated and that no indexing into such arrays takes place within `Total`.

You can compute `hmat` with

```
hmat2= chmat[nμ, ne, δ, β, avec, nvec, svec];//AbsoluteTiming//First
hmat==hmat2

(* 0.003411 *)
(* True *)
```

On my machine, this results in a 600-fold speed-up.

**Addendum:**

This need not to be the end of the story. By deactivating some security checks and replacing `Part` with `Compile`GetElement` I even get a speed-up factor of over 2500 (compared to the original code). This is how it looks:

```
chmat = With[{ccfxn = cfxn}, 
   Compile[{{nm, _Integer}, {ne, _Integer}, {d, _Real}, {b, _Real},  {avec, _Real, 2}, {nvec, _Real, 1}, {svec, _Real, 1}},
    Block[{n0, n1, n2, n3, h1, h2, tmp, tmp2},
     Table[
      n0 = Compile`GetElement[nvec, nm0];
      n1 = Compile`GetElement[nvec, nm1];
      tmp = 0.;
      Do[
       n2 = Compile`GetElement[nvec, nm2];
       n3 = Compile`GetElement[nvec, nm3];
       tmp2 = (ccfxn[n1, n0, n3, n2] - ccfxn[n1, n3, n0, n2]);
       Do[
         tmp += tmp2 Compile`GetElement[avec, j, nm3] Compile`GetElement[avec, j, nm2],
        {j, 1, ne}],
       {nm2, 1, nm}, {nm3, 1, nm}];
      d tmp + If[nm0 == nm1, (n0^2 Pi^2 + b Compile`GetElement[svec, nm0]), 0.],
      {nm0, 1, nm}, {nm1, 1, nm}]
     ],
    CompilationTarget -> "C",
    CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True},
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
    ]];
```

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @DelaramNematollahi You're welcome!

Comment: I have another question Henrik, If I use this code and calculate the Eigen energies and Eigenvectors of chmat, and replace the new eigen vectors with the previous avec, I can do that, as far as I do it manually. But as I use Table to apply the iteration it gives me error. I will edit my question and add my question to it. Could you please help me with this also?

Comment: @DelaramNematollahi I will see what I can do for you. Maybe it is better to start a new question; it might get confusing otherwise. At the moment, it sounds like `Nest` or `NestList` instead of `Table` might help you.

Comment: oh, ok. sorry I just modified this. should I ask it in a separate question now?

Comment: Could you take a look at a new modification I want to implement?

Comment: Could you take a look at a new modification I want to implement?

Answer (score 5):

This is around 30-40 times faster than the original, so not as fast as Henrik's Compile version.

I replaced the inner loop with `Outer` and rearranged slightly to avoid computing the same thing multiple times - this includes memoizing fxn and moving the avec multiplications outside the loop.

I also expressed fxn differently and changed some of the symbol names, this was not for performance but to help me understand the code better.

```
avec = Developer`ToPackedArray@N@{
     {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
nvec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
svec = {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};

ne = 3; nμ = 12; δ = -50; β = 1;

Clear[g, fxn]

g[x_, y_] := 8 x y/((x^2 - y^2)^2 π^2)

mem : fxn[x_, x_, u_, u_] := mem = N[1/6 (1 - 3/(x^2 π^2) - 3/(u^2 π^2))]
mem : fxn[x_, x_, u_, v_] := mem = N@If[OddQ[u + v], 0, g[u, v]]
mem : fxn[x_, y_, u_, u_] := mem = N@If[OddQ[x + y], 0, g[x, y]]
mem : fxn[x_, y_, u_, v_] := mem = N@If[EvenQ[x + y] || EvenQ[u + v], 0, -2 g[x, y] g[u, v]]

a = Transpose[avec];
oa = Outer[Times, a, a, 1];

hmat = Table[
   n0 = nvec[[i]]; n1 = nvec[[j]];
   h1 = (n0^2 π^2 + β svec[[i]]) KroneckerDelta[i, j];
   of = Outer[fxn[n1, n0, #1, #2] - fxn[n1, #1, n0, #2] &, nvec, nvec];
   h2 = δ Total[of oa, Infinity];
   h1 + h2, {i, nμ}, {j, nμ}] // Timing
```

Answer (score 1):

The reworked code for the second answer could look like this. Here, we need  also the definitions of `chmat` and `cfxn` from my other post. It is not meaningful to include the code for `chmat` with the `Compile` command in the `Table`: `Compile` creates the function `chmat` that is highly optimized for multiple execution. We can simply reuse the function `chmat`.

Apart from that, there was some bad syntax, e.g. due to commands in the loop that were not well seperated by semicoli. Also, the rest of the code can be shortened a bit. `Eigensystem` always throws orthonormalized eigenvalues when supplied with numerical arguments. So no normalization is needed. The sign computations at the end are probably to prevent the rows of `avec` to flip back and forth. Since some of the first entries tend to be close to `zero`, a sign rule that depends only on the first entry is not very stable. Hence I took the freedom to enforce that the *sum* of each row of `avec` is nonnegative. The table returns now pairs of the distances of current to former instance of `avec` and the desired value `en`. As can be read of easily, the method converges nicely after a few dozen of iterations.

```
Table[
 hmat = chmat[n\[Mu], ne, \[Delta], \[Beta], avec, nvec, svec];
 {evals, evecs} = Eigensystem[hmat];
 pos = Ordering[evals][[1 ;; ne]];
 bvec = Map[x \[Function] If[Total[x] < 0, -x, x], evecs[[pos]]];
 residual = Max[Abs[avec - bvec]];
 avec = bvec;
 {residual, Total[evals[[pos]]]},
 {j, 1, 30}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your great explanation. I learned a lot. I just wanted to ask you what are the other possible ways I can get master in mathematica. Is there any special way you would suggest instead of the asking, solving I am currently doing?

Comment: @DelaramNematollahi You can find a quite comprehensive list of advices here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice. The best advice that I can give you personally is to learn about `Function` and `Map`: While procedural programming with `Do` and `Table` is good for compilation (in this case, one leaves the Mathematica universe and indirectly writes C-code), functional programming helps enormously to produce decently fast and expressive code.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again, I don't know why I am getting this error: "CompiledFunction::cfne: Numerical error encountered; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation." if I use this term for code in cfxn: "code = -((
       16 A B^2 E^-B ((-1)^(1 + n1a + n1b) + (-1)^(
          1 + n2a + n2b) + (1 + (-1)^(n1a + n1b + n2a + n2b)) E^
           B) n1a n1b n2a n2b \[Pi]^4)/((B^2 + (n1a - 
             n1b)^2 \[Pi]^2) (B^2 + (n1a + 
             n1b)^2 \[Pi]^2) (B^2 + (n2a - 
             n2b)^2 \[Pi]^2) (B^2 + (n2a + n2b)^2 \[Pi]^2)))}"

Comment: Hi. I think that happens because you haven't declared all symbols (e.g. `A` and `B`) in `code` as arguments to `Compile`. Please, look up `Compile` in the documentation to learn what it actually does and how to set it up correctly. See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1803. The function `CompilePrint` in the "CompiledFunctionTools`" package might also be quite helpful.

Comment: @ Henrik Schumacher  could you look at this question I asked? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/158445/how-can-i-make-this-program-work-faster