# Local variable in a compiled function?

Tags: compile

With `Block` or `Module` we can specify variables local to their scope in curly brackets like this:

```
myFunction[x_]:=Block[{localVariable},...]
```

How can we do the same with [compiled functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile.html)? The manual states that

> Compiled code does not handle numerical precision and local variables in the same way as ordinary Wolfram Language code.

but there does not seem to be an example on how to define a local variable within the scope of a compiled function. How would a trivial minimal example look like?

Comment: You simply can use `Block` or `Module` in the body of the compiled function. It does not matter; both ways just tell `Compile` to make the variables local.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Is it possible for a compiled function to take in an Association (dictionary in Python, map in C++) as input? Can it take as input another compiled function? Can a compiled function be recursive (call itself)?

Comment: No, `Associations` are not compilable. No, function pointers cannot be used as arguments of a  `CompiledFunction`. Yes, I think recursive calls are possible (with some trick that you have to look up on this site), but I would really discourage to use them because  -- IRCC -- they are realized by `MainEvaluate` which pretty much defeats the purpose of `Compile`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What configuration one chooses depends on the specific needs of the function one is compiling and other general considerations about the relative place and function of that piece of code in the rest of one's script/program.

With that in mind, one way to achieve what is being asked is to use `With`; this way, one can incorporate simple constants in a compiled function, eg

```
(* a compiled function with a constant *)
f = With[{alpha=3.507}, 
   Compile[{{x,_Real}}, 2*alpha-x*1.09]
 ]
```

The approach presented above addresses the need to use "constants* inside the compiled function; local *variables* that can take on *different* values during the lifespan of the local scope need to be introduced in a different way.

```
f = Compile[{{x,_Real}}, Module[{y=x+3.},
    Log[y]
   ]]
```

This last example, contrived as it might be, introduces the use of local variables inside a compiled function with the help of `Module`.

The first answer to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-compile-effectively) question, has *a lot* of packed information on the use of `Compile`; there are also examples of uses with compilation that uses local variables.

Also, as a side-note, the first answer to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs) question demonstrates the various scoping structures available in *Mathematica*. 
I include this last link, although it is not *directly* related to compilation, because the question involves the use of `Block`; I have refrained from using it in this answer, as the linked response suggests that it should be used in those cases it is absolutely necessasary to, otherwise `Module` will suffice.

Comment: On this topic, I am having trouble using Compile. Why does the code `f:=Compile[{{M,_Integer,2},{m,_Integer}}, Module[{l},l=ConstantArray[{},m]; l[[M[[1]]]]=Transpose@{M[[2]]}; l] ]; f[{{8,9,10},{2,3,1}},10]` return `CompiledFunction::cfn: Numerical error encountered at instruction 8; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.`?

Comment: @Leo 1. usually a `Compile` function is `Set` not `SetDelayed` much like you'd do with a `Function` but that's not what's causing you trouble. 2. you are using `Compile` in order to perform some structural transformation on the input while usually `Compile` is used to speed up numerical calculations, but that's not either why you're having trouble 3. `Compile` complains because it doesn't know how to treat `ConstantArray[{}, m]` which, in your example,  resembles a $10\times0$ matrix. One way you can avoid the message is by writing instead `ConstantArray[{0}, m]`. Hope this makes sense...