# Function[{u}, g[u]] vs. Function[u, g[u]] : In which the behavior between differs?

Tags: function-construction, documentation

```
Function[{u}, g[u]] 
Function[u, g[u]]
```

The documentation lists both variants without specifying the difference. 
Does the behavior differ in some circumstances?

Comment: No difference, just some flexibility in the syntax for single-variable functions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no functional difference between `Function[{u}, g[u]]` and
`Function[u, g[u]]`.  The following difference in speed is small but consistent on my machine (MacBook Pro):

```
foo = Range[5*10^6];
foo[[1]] = 1.;

Function[x, x] /@ foo; // RepeatedTiming
Function[{x}, x] /@ foo; // RepeatedTiming
(*
  {2.4, Null}
  {2.0, Null}
*)
```

It's a small difference compared to the execution time of more complicated function bodies.

*Note on the example:*
The line `foo[[1]] = 1.` unpacks the array `foo` and prevents it from being packed.  This in turn prevents the functions from being auto-compiled by `Map` (`/@`).  If the functions are compiled, then all differences between them are erased.

Comment: Where is this autocompile feature of `Map` documented?  (More than [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compile/tutorial/Operation.html).)

Comment: @Alan If you want official documentation, it is also mentioned [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html#488928370) but it is not fully documented AFAIK. If you want a more thorough albeit unofficial discussion, look for the auto-compilation section of [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1816/4999).