# How to make a compiled version of a function?

Tags: matrix, compile

I'm trying to make a compiled version of this function

```
LN = Compile[{{a, _Real, 1}, {CMat, _Real}, {P, _Real, 
     2}, {OMG, _Real, 2}}, 
   Module[{Mat, CoPart, CovT, root, Eigs}, 
    Mat = Developer`ToPackedArray[CMat];
    CoPart = ArrayFlatten[Mat[[a, a]]];
    CovT = P[1, Length[a] - 1].CoPart.P[1, Length[a] - 1];
    root = Eigenvalues[-OMG[Length[a]].CovT.OMG[Length[a]].CovT];
    Eigs = Delete[Sqrt[root], Table[{2*i}, {i, 1, Length[root]/2}]];
    Sum[-Log2[Min[1, Eigs[[i]]]], {i, 1, Length[Eigs]}]], 
   Parallelization -> True]
```

but I face some errors as follows

```
Compile::cplist: Compile`$8 should be a tensor of type Integer, Real, or Complex; evaluation will use the uncompiled function.

Compile::cplist: Compile`$8.CoPart should be a tensor of type Integer, Real, or Complex; evaluation will use the uncompiled function.

Compile::cplist: Compile`$8 should be a tensor of type Integer, Real, or Complex; evaluation will use the uncompiled function.

General::stop: Further output of Compile::cplist will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

CMat is an n×n matrix of 2×2 blocks, and P and OMG are some 2n×2n matrices.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest starting from here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104031/1871

Comment: Here an incomplete list of issues: ``Developer`ToPackedArray[CMat]`` in code to be compiled does not make sense; whenever `CMat` is an input array of a compiled functions, it _is_ already packed. Morever, `Eigenvalues` cannot be compiled (it _is_ already essentially a library function) and indexing into `OMG` should be done with` OMG[[Length[a]]]` instead of `OMG[Length[a]]`. `Parallelization -> True` without `RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}` does not do anything. The rank specification of `CMat` is certainly wrong; it should be something like `{CMat, _Real, 4}`.

Comment: `Mat[[a, a]]` is going to be troublesome if `a` is a list of reals.

Comment: Thank you. 'Forgot to say: `OMG` is a square matrix function and the argument is its dimension, `P` matrix as well. Unfortunately, the input for compile function is a list of integers e.g. `LN[{1,2,3}]` and maybe parallelization wouldn't make any sense. Unluckily, I don't know what the rank of a block matrix is. `CMat` is a MxM matrix of 2x2 blocks, by the way. Unfortunately, `a` is a list of integers.