# Speeding up nested NIntegrate with convolution

Tags: numerical-integration

I'd like to calculate:

$ p(y_a, y_b | \phi_d) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\phi_d' \Big( \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} d\theta \exp(\frac{-(y_a-sin\theta)^2}{2v_a})\Big[\exp(\frac{-(y_b-sin(\theta+\phi_d')^2}{2v_b})+\exp(\frac{-(y_b-sin(\theta-\phi_d')^2}{2v_b}) \Big] \Big) \exp(\frac{-(\phi_d-\phi_d')^2}{2v_d})$

So there's an inner integral and then a convolution.

I'm currently doing this (changed the range of the convolution and results are fine). But I need to do this for many pairs of {ya,yb} to get a distribution as a function of $\phi_d$. Any suggestions for how to speed it up?

Thank you SO Much!!

```
ϕlist = Range[0.5, 0.35*Pi, 0.01];
Length[ϕlist]
pAllDP = {};

Timing[For[n = 1, n <= Length[yA], n++, pOneDP = {}; 
   For[i = 1, i <= Length[ϕlist], i++, 
    probIntegrand[θ_] := 
     Exp[(-(dpA - Sin[θ])^2/(2*varianceA))*
     (Exp[-(dpB - Sin[θ + ϕd])^2/(2*varianceB)] + 
      Exp[-(dpB - Sin[θ - ϕd])^2/(2*varianceB)])] /. dpA -> yA[[n]] /. 
       dpB -> yB[[n]] /. ϕd -> ϕlist[[i]];

pOffset[(z_)?NumericQ] := pOffest[z] = 
  NIntegrate[probIntegrand[θ], {θ, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, 
   MaxRecursion -> 20, AccuracyGoal -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> 7];

pDifferential[ϕ_] := Exp[-(ϕd - ϕ)^2/(2*varianceD)] /. ϕd -> ϕlist[[i]];
pTotal = NIntegrate[pOffset[z]*pDifferential[z], {z, 0, 2*Pi}];

AppendTo[pOneDP, pTotal];]; AppendTo[pAllDP, pOneDP];];]
```

Comment: Compare yours with `...Timing[ pAllDP=Table[ pOneDP=Table[ probIntegrand[...
pTotal = NIntegrate[pOffset[z]*pDifferential[z], {z,0,2*Pi}], {i,Length[\[Phi]list]}], {n,Length[yA]}]; ]` Replacing `For` and `AppendTo` with `Table` is supposed to be faster.

Answer (score 3):

I've benefited using [ParallelDo](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelDo.html) or [ParallelTable](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelTable.html) instead of `For` many times. You should check them out since they're easy to use.

Also, using [compile](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-compile-effectively) can give you immense speed up. There are many examples and tips on using *compile* and *parallelization* in Mathematica across the internet.

I also recommend reading [this post](https://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/07/10-tips-for-writing-fast-mathematica-code/) on *10 tips on writing faster Mathematica codes*, a life-saver for me! Hope this helps.

**Note:** Adding a `ParallelTable` to @Bill 's comment should it get even faster:

```
\[Phi]list = Range[0.5, 0.35*Pi, 0.01]; 
Timing[
    pAllDP = ParallelTable[
        pOneDP = Table[
            probIntegrand[\[Theta]_] := 
                Exp[(-(dpA - Sin[\[Theta]])^2/(2*varianceA))* (Exp[-(dpB - Sin[\[Theta] + \[Phi]d])^2/(2*varianceB)] + Exp[-(dpB - Sin[\[Theta] - \[Phi]d])^2/(2*varianceB)])] /. dpA -> yA[[n]] /. dpB -> yB[[n]] /. \[Phi]d -> \[Phi]list[[i]]; 
           pOffset[(z_)?NumericQ] := pOffest[z] = NIntegrate[probIntegrand[\[Theta]], {\[Theta], -Pi/2, Pi/2}, MaxRecursion -> 20, AccuracyGoal -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> 7]; 
           pDifferential[\[Phi]_] := Exp[-(\[Phi]d - \[Phi])^2/(2*varianceD)] /. \[Phi]d -> \[Phi]list[[i]]; 
           pTotal = NIntegrate[pOffset[z]*pDifferential[z], {z, 0, 2*Pi}]
           ,{i,Length[\[Phi]list]}}]
        ,{n,Length[yA]]}}];
   ]
```

Comment: Thanks. This was actually the same time as doing the For loop but the notation is cleaner. I've gotten this down to 17s using:  Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}  Any other suggestions for how I could manipulate this integral would be much appreciated. I've gotten the suggestion of maybe trying to pre-calculate parts, but not sure how to do this...