# Error on using Compile[]

Tags: compile

My code is below.

```
deltaX = 1/128;
W=256;
Mmax=40;

lPoly = ParallelTable[
   LegendreP[
    order, (-1.) + (deltaX/2.) + ((index - 1.)*deltaX)], 
{order, 0, Mmax}, {index, 1, W}];

XPoly = Compile[{{index, _Integer}}, 
   Block[{}, 
    polyMatrix = 
     PadRight[Table[lPoly[[m - n + 1, index]], {m, 0, Mmax}, {n, 0, m}]]; 
    polyMatrix], CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True, 
   RuntimeOptions -> {"CatchMachineIntegerOverflow" -> False}];
```

If I run `XPoly[1]`, it will return:

```
CompiledFunction::cfse :  Compiled expression {{1.},{-0.996094,1.},<<48>>,<<71>>} should be a machine-size real number.
```

I have encountered this kinda error multiple times, sometimes it solved. But I dont know why.

Comment: If you decide to turn to `Compile`, I suggest starting from reading this post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104031/1871 And now you're against rule (2) and rule (6) there.

Comment: The main problem is that your `Table` constructs a ragged array (rows are are not all the same length).  Ragged arrays are not allowed in `Compile`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks Mike. Actually I use `PadRight` here. For avoiding confusion, I didnt post it. If you mean constructing ragged array is not allowed, it would solve my problem.

Comment: Even with `PadRight`, you first generate a ragged array before it is padded. But you can apply `PadRight` outside of `Compile` to generate `XPoly` as rectangular array. Also make sure that all `0` are actually floating point `0.`. (I am not sure whether `Compile` is clever enough to convert them on its own.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work better: It generates a rectangular array (filled with zeroes) first and than fills in the entries:

```
deltaX = 1./128;
W = 256;
Mmax = 40;
lPoly = Developer`ToPackedArray[
   Table[
     LegendreP[order, -1. + 0.5 deltaX + (index - 1.) deltaX], 
     {order, 0, Mmax}, {index, 1, W}]
   ];

XPoly = Compile[{{index, _Integer}, {lPoly, _Real, 2}},
   Block[{polyMatrix, Mmax},
    Mmax = Length[lPoly] - 1;
    polyMatrix = Table[0., {Mmax + 1}, {Mmax + 1}];
    Do[
     polyMatrix[[m + 1, n + 1]] = lPoly[[m - n + 1, index]]
     ,
     {m, 0, Mmax}, {n, 0, m}];
    
    polyMatrix
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True
   ];

test = XPoly[{1, 2, 3}, lPoly];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Henrik!

Comment: You're welcome!