# Compiled Function is slower than non-compiled version?

Tags: performance-tuning, compile

I need to maximize a function numerically, thus the speed of this function is very important. Here is the most time consuming part of this function.

```
pPoisson[lambda_, mu_, x_, 
  y_] := (E^(-lambda - mu)*lambda^x*mu^y)/(x!*y!)
list[a1_, b1_, a2_, b2_, c_, upper_ : 15] := 
 Module[{lambda = Exp[a1 - b2 + c], mu = Exp[a2 - b1], m},
  m = Table[pPoisson[lambda, mu, i, j], {j, 0, upper}, {i, 0, upper}];
  {Total[UpperTriangularize[m, 1], Infinity], Total[Diagonal[m]], 
   Total[LowerTriangularize[m, -1], Infinity]}]
Do[list[1.3, 0.6, 0.2, 0.2, 0.17, 15], {i, 1000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.06158, Null} *)
```

The `pPoisson` is the product of 2 Poisson Distribution probability mass function. The function `list` generates a matrix of `pPoisson` and calculates the sum of the matrix upper, diagnal and lower part. Running `list` 1000 times takes 1.06 s. This is not the speed I would like to have. Therefore, I tried to compile it, but the compiled version seems to be 2x slower.

```
clist = Compile[{{a1, _Real}, {b1, _Real}, {a2, _Real}, {b2, _Real}, \
{c, _Real}, {upper, _Integer}},
  Module[{lambda = Exp[a1 - b2 + c], mu = Exp[a2 - b1], i, j},
   {Sum[(Exp[(-lambda - mu)]*lambda^i*mu^j)/(Product[x, {x, 1, i}]*
        Product[x, {x, 1, j}]), {i, 1, upper}, {j, 0, i - 1}],
    Sum[(Exp[(-lambda - mu)]*lambda^i*
        mu^i)/(Product[x, {x, 1, i}]^2), {i, 0, upper}],
    Sum[(Exp[(-lambda - mu)]*lambda^i*mu^j)/(Product[x, {x, 1, i}]*
        Product[x, {x, 1, j}]), {j, 1, upper}, {i, 0, j - 1}]}],
  CompilationTarget -> "C",
  Parallelization -> True, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
Do[clist[1.3, 0.6, 0.2, 0.2, 0.17, 15], {i, 1000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.9038489`, Null} *)
```

Any idea why and how to accelarate it?

Comment: By using immediate assignments (`=`) instead of delayed assignments (`:=`) you may speed up your code quite a bit even without compilation. https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/39-immediate-and-delayed-values.html

Comment: Look up `CompilePrint`, `MainEvaluate`, and other pointers [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-compile-effectively) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slowness is due to several instances of [`MainEvaluate`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104031/4999).  I replaced the `Product` factorials with `Gamma`, which turns out to be compilable.

```
clist = Compile[{{a1, _Real}, {b1, _Real}, {a2, _Real}, {b2, _Real}, 
   {c, _Real}, {upper, _Integer}},
  Module[{
    lambda = Exp[a1 - b2 + c],
    mu = Exp[a2 - b1],
    i, j},
   {Sum[(Exp[(-lambda - mu)]*lambda^i*mu^j)/(Gamma[1 + i]*
        Gamma[1 + j]), {i, 1, upper}, {j, 0, i - 1}]
    , Sum[(Exp[(-lambda - mu)]*lambda^i*mu^i)/(Gamma[1 + i]^2), {i, 0,
       upper}]
    , Sum[(Exp[(-lambda - mu)]*lambda^i*mu^j)/(Gamma[1 + i]*
        Gamma[1 + j]), {j, 1, upper}, {i, 0, j - 1}]
    }]
  , CompilationTarget -> "C"
  (*,Parallelization\[Rule]True*) (* useless without Listable *)
  , RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]

Do[clist[1.3, 0.6, 0.2, 0.2, 0.17, 15], {i, 1000}]; // RepeatedTiming
(*  {0.0067, Null}  *)
```

The OP's `clist` took about 2 sec.