# Numerical errors in compiled function involving real and complex numbers as output

Tags: complex, compile, scoping, pure-function, computational-complexity

I am trying to use the `Compile` command in Mathematica to reduce the computation time because of its fast execution within Mathematica and ability to use the `C` compiler for even faster computation. As this is my first time using the command, I referred to the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile.html) and some usage by [Leonid Shilfrin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/81/leonid-shifrin) and others as an answer to this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-compile-effectively).

After searching for a lot, I was not able to get some satisfying answers regarding the `Compile` command involving both `Real` and `Complex` outputs. I am trying to write a code analogous to my actual code which involves a similar problem just to get rid of many parameters and increased complexity. The function mentioned here takes real (random numbers generated by `RandomReal` in actual problem) inputs mentioned explicitly and returns a mandatory real and complex (maybe real in some case) output.

```
somefunction = Compile[{x,_Real},
        Module[{data},
          data = ArcSin[x]//N;
          {x, data}]
       ]
```

which works fine without any error within the input range `-1 <=  x <= 1`, but raises an error beyond the specified range due to the complex output.

```
someFunction[0.5]
(*{0.5, 0.523599}*)
someFunction[2]
CompiledFunction::cfn: Numerical error encountered at instruction 1; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.
(*{2, 1.5708 - 1.31696 I}*)
```

The answer is indeed correct in the latter case but the error produced while executing creates problems (making the computation even slower in the actual case). Using `` CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint[someFunction] `` to debug this issue, I found that there is no room to accommodate `Complex` number as an output of `ArcSin` in this case.

I need to get rid of this error. In trying to do so, I have tried using `CompilationOptions` with `{"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> False}` and `{"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}` following some answers here without actually knowing its utility. I had also tried to use `Join` to evade `MainEvaluate` in my original problem but none of this worked quite well. I need to use a `Module` inside `Compile` and encountered errors while trying to define any sort of pure function. The output is also within `Module` to minimize memory usage. I would also like to know what the letters `R`, `A`, `C`, `I` etc. mean in the output of the `CompilePrint` command so that I can debug similar issues by myself in future.

My actual computation is very CPU and Memory intensive because the actual function (similar to `someFunction` mentioned above) takes 12 (up to 20 in some case) arguments (generated by `RandomReal`) with 8 outputs (some of which may be complex in some cases) and it loops over `10^9` times which I am going to implement via a script file with `.m` extension. This is the reason behind using `Compile` and `Module` rather than using a pure function with `SetDelayed` symbol.

It would be extremely helpful if someone can guide me through this problem or mention any similar posts related to this kind of problem which I might have missed. Thanks for any suggestions in advance.

Comment: Does `somefunction = Compile[{{x, _Complex}},
  Module[{data},
   data = ArcSin[x];
   {x, data}]
  ]` work for you?

Comment: Or `somefunction = Compile[{{x, _Real}},
  Module[{data, y = 0. I},
   y = x;
   data = ArcSin[y];
   {y, data}]
  ]`?

Comment: This works fine. Thanks @Michael E2, for this simple and elegant solution. Although this makes ```x``` in a general complex in the output. Is there a way for better formatting in the output (use the complex number only if the value is complex by itself) ?

Comment: Maybe `Chop[somefunction[2]]`? Note `Compile` can return a list consisting only of values all of the same type. It cannot deal with arbitrary expressions the way general Mathematica functions can. It’s a restriction that helps compiled functions be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelE2 . This was exactly what I wanted. On a side note, it would be helpful for me if you kindly mention briefly about the letters ```A```, ```R```, ```C```, ```I``` in the output of ```CompilePrint```? This would help me to understand how ```Compile``` works and debug such errors by myself.

Comment: Register types mainly: A = argument, T = tensor, R = real, C = complex, I = integer, B = boolean. The integer following the letter is the register number. T(Xn) indicates a tensor of type X and array depth n. So T(C1)0 indicates a complex vector register #0, T(R2)3 indicates a real matrix register #3.

Comment: This was extremely helpful. Thanks a lot. @MichaelE2

Comment: You're welcome.