# Set return type in compilation of a function of list

Tags: list-manipulation, compile

I hope to compile a complicated function with the process that create an complex list and sum over it. However, system always tell me the output should be a real number and I cannot change them. How can I set type of return or is there other methods to solve this?

```
In[1]:= Needs["CCompilerDriver`GenericCCompiler`"]

In[2]:= ot = Subdivide @@ N[{-3, 3, 3600*4}];

In[3]:= st = RandomReal[1, 10000];

In[4]:= ucgf = Function[{om}, Total[1/(om + I*0.001 - st), 1]]

Out[4]= Function[{om}, Total[1/(om + I 0.001 - st), 1]]

In[5]:= gf1 = 
 Compile[{{omega, _Real}}, ucgf[omega], RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
  RuntimeAttributes -> Listable, Parallelization -> True, 
  CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}, 
  CompilationTarget -> "C"]

In[6]:= gf1[1]

During evaluation of In[6]:= CompiledFunction::cfse: Compiled expression 70281.2 -15548.9 I should be a machine-size real number.

During evaluation of In[6]:= CompiledFunction::cfexe: Could not complete external evaluation; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.

Out[6]= 70281.2 - 15548.9 I

In[7]:= ucgf2[om_] := Total[1/(om + I*0.001 - st), 1]

In[8]:= gf2 = 
 Compile[{{omega, _Real}}, ucgf2[omega], {{ucgf2[_], _Complex, 0}}, 
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", RuntimeAttributes -> Listable, 
  Parallelization -> True, 
  CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}, 
  CompilationTarget -> "C"]

In[9]:= ucgf2[2]// AbsoluteTiming

Out[9]= {0.0002784, 70016.2 - 16548.8 I}

In[10]:= gf[2]// AbsoluteTiming

Out[10]= {0.0002784, 70016.2 - 16548.8 I}
```

We can see in `gf1`, Mathematica compile the return should be a real number and directly run in interpreter. And in `gf2`, I define an external function `ucgf2` then add into compilation, and declear it is a complex number. Now the kernel does not throw an error, but not compile at all. The time elapse of compiled function and original `ucgf2` are the same, no acceleration. Therefore, is there a method to compile successfully without error and improve its efficiency?

Comment: `ot` is defined but not used in your code

Comment: Have you read this?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104031/1871

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that your compiled code is 2x faster than the uncompiled code

```
SeedRandom[1];
st = RandomReal[1, 10000];


fc =
  Compile[
   {{omega, _Real}},
   Block[
    {list},
    list = 1/(omega + I*0.001 - st);
    Total[list]
    ],
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed",
   RuntimeAttributes -> Listable,
   Parallelization -> True,
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True},
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];
{fcTime, fcResult} = RepeatedTiming[fc@Range[1000]];


f[omega_] := Total[1/(omega + I*0.001 - st)];
{fTime, fResult} = RepeatedTiming[f /@ Range[1000]];

fcTime (* 0.0448778 *)
fTime (* 0.0905876 *)

fcResult == fResult (* True *)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I understand. You use `CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}`. This makes great contribution.