How to quickly check if compiled code calls MainEvaluate?
Consider the following test compiled code:
func[x_] = x^2;
func1[x_] = x^3;
compiled = Hold@Compile[{{x, _Real}}, Module[{res = 0.},
      res += func[x];
      res += func1[x];
      res], CompilationTarget -> "C"] /. DownValues@func // ReleaseHold

It calls MainEvaluate since func1 is not DownValued, which may be seen using CompilePrint:
<< CompiledFunctionTools`
CompilePrint@compiled

For this example, the output of CompilePrint is pretty short, and the problem may be easily localized. However, for a generic case of a code involving many elementary operations, it becomes a mess to find if the output contains MainEvaluate. Would it be possible to extract all the lines of CompilePrint containing MainEvaluate?
Edit
It may be the following:
CheckIfCompiled[code_] := Block[{},
  << CompiledFunctionTools`;
  compiledPrintOutput = 
   ToString[CompilePrint[code], FormatType -> OutputForm];
  lines = StringSplit[compiledPrintOutput, "\n"];
  mainEvaluateLines = 
   Select[lines, StringContainsQ[#, "MainEvaluate"] &];
  IfIsCompiled = If[Length[mainEvaluateLines] == 0, True, False];
  {IfIsCompiled, mainEvaluateLines}
  ] 

So I would like to ask an additional question. Let us assume that we have many compiled codes in the notebook. How to make a check that automatically finds all the compiled codes, launches the routine above for them, and returns the overall "True" or "False" decision on whether all the codes are compiled, and displays the list of those that are not compiled, together with the suspicious strings?

This is mentioned here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1108/1871 and here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1814/1871
